# Does Cte in Sql server executed once or each time it is referenced?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a dummy table

```
create table emp
(
  id int,
  name varchar,
  sal int
)

with cte1 as(
select * from emp where name like 'a%'
),  
cte2 as (
select * from cte1 where sal > 100
),
cte3 as (
select * from cte1 where id != 1223
)
select * from cte2
union all
select * from ct3
```

Does using cte in this manner guarantee that cte1, cte2, cte3 will be run once only?

Though I can check the query plan but will that guarantee that the behaviour will not change if the data is changed and next time optimzer decides to do it in another way?

Comment: Every time it's referenced.

Comment: Each time it's referenced. In this case, `emp` would be referenced twice. (As can be seen in the query's [query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hym_NcCBS))

Answer (score 4):

*"Does using cte in this manner guarantee that cte1, cte2, cte3 will be run once only?"* No. The query you have here will not "run" `cte1` once, it'll run it twice. This can be seen in the query's [query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hym_NcCBS) where you can see `emp` appears twice.

This is because, in the final `SELECT` you reference both `cte3` and `cte2` in the final select. Both of these reference `cte1`, which in turn references `emp`. As a result the call to `cte3` and `cte2` results in 2 calls to the object `emp`.

Technically, if you wanted, you *could* rewrite the above to the below; which might help you see why `emp` is referenced twice:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT *
            FROM emp
            WHERE [name] LIKE 'a%') AS cte1
      WHERE sal > 100) AS cte2
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT *
            FROM emp
            WHERE [name] LIKE 'a%') AS cte1
      WHERE id != 1223) AS cte3;
```